# Why a Name Function Expression not available outside function body

Tags: javascript

The Named Function Expression which is defined as

```
var ninja = function myNinja();
```

has a behavior which is not able to get through my head.

Have a look at the below code

```
 var ninja = function myNinja() {
   console.log(typeof myNinja) //prints 'function'
 };
 console.log(typeof myNinja) //prints 'undefined'
```

Now, `myNinja` is a named function and as far as I know javascript allow the named function to go beyond the scope of its own function.

This is creating confusion in my head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now, `myNinja` is a named function and as far as I know javascript allow the named function to go beyond the scope of its own function.

Only in a function *declaration*. It's specifically *not* the case for a named function *expression*. It's just how this is defined in the specification.

All the gory details are [in the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13), the most relevant bit is:

> NOTE The *Identifier* in a *FunctionExpression* can be referenced from inside the *FunctionExpression's* *FunctionBody* to allow the function to call itself recursively. However, unlike in a *FunctionDeclaration*, the *Identifier* in a *FunctionExpression* cannot be referenced from and does not affect the scope enclosing the *FunctionExpression*.

So if you changed your code to:

```
function myNinja() {
    console.log(typeof myNinja) //prints 'function'
}
var ninja = myNinja;
console.log(typeof myNinja) //prints 'function' (now we're using a declaration)
```

...since that uses a function *declaration*, `myNinja` is added to the scope in which it's defined. (The declaration is also hoisted, like all declarations; it's not processed as part of the step-by-step code the way expressions are.)

Comment: Just as a side note: IE8 and earlier had a bug where they processed NFEs as *both* declarations *and* expressions, and so you'd have the name in scope where you were expecting it, details: http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/09/double-take.html Fixed in IE9 and up.

Comment: That perfectly made sense. So it's mainly because function expressions are entirely different from function declaration. Thank you for a swift explanation.

Answer (score 3):

No, the function is not a named function, it's a function expression.

A function expression can optionally have a name. Ref:

```
function [name]([param1[, param2[, ..., paramN]]]) {
   statements
}
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function

About the function name:

> **name**
>   The function name. Can be omitted, in which case the function
>   is anonymous. *The name is only local to the function body.*

(Emphasis mine.)

A named function has a very similar syntax, but it's a declaration, not an expression.

Comment: *"No, the function is not a named function, it's a function expression."* Yes, it **is** a named function. Specifically, a named function created via a named function expression.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: It's specifically a named function expression. Calling just a named function would be confusing because that is used for declared functions, not function expressions.

Comment: Both declared functions and functions created via named function expressions are named functions. It's kinda right there in the name "named function expression." :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your function is being stored in the variable `ninja`, so you can't access it by the function name, only the variable name:

```
console.log(typeof ninja)
```

This differs from a function declaration like below, which in contrast can be accessed by the function name:

```
function ninja(){

}
```

There are other differences, such as the latter being 'hoisted', unlike the former.